# Visual Studio Error "make sure the path or internet address is correct"

Tags: c#

Error Message Box Pops out and said

> "file:///%7B0%7D make sure the path or internet address is correct"

the line of code which sent this error v

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(string.Format("file:///{0}/Monaco/Monaco.html", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

Comment: Did you intend to access the Application Executing (./bin/debug) directory? Try Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: seems like not working :l

Comment: Well You got to debug what values/path you see in these standard envrionment variable. As a hack fix you can try Path.GetFullPath(".")